# Pygame - When conditions are met, displaying pictures and stopping music?

Tags: python, image, audio, pygame

Sound first - I currently have background music playing but I'd like to stop it and play a victory or defeat song when the user wins or loses. At the moment I am unable to get the background music to stop. I'm assuming I put the command to stop the music and play the other file in the condition. Am I correct in this?

I have tried things such as bgm_music = True while bgm_music == true: code and during the condition bgm_music = False but this stops my program from working.

EDIT - Okay, for the music just loading a new song works perfectly so I think I'm all-right with the sound section.

As for the picture. I'd like to do the same as the music essentially. I want to display a victory or defeat image on top of everything once the user wins or fails. Again, I have tried a similar boolean thing as above but to no avail.

EDIT 2 - I have managed to display the picture but I need to know how to get it on top (Currently the sprites are on top of it)

Comment: Setting a boolean related to your background music stops the program from working? I think we're going to have to see some of your code to help you with this.

Comment: Well, it didn't stop the program from working, it just didn't load anything. Anyway, it's fixed now but the image doesn't appear on top.

Comment: for the picture to be on top you simply have to blit the picture in the correct order, there is no easy way to change this during runtime

Comment: Thank you. I shall have a play around with the positions.

Answer (score 0):

It think you should keep track of different states, example:

- 1: Gameplay
- 2: Song
- 3: Game Over screen

Then execute code according to the state in your main loop:

```
if state == 1:
    # gameplay code
    # if over start music and change to state 2
elif state == 2:
    # song playing
    # decrese song_counter
    if song_counter == 0:
        # stop music
        # change to state 3
elif state == 3:
    # blit game over image
    # decrease game_over_counter
    if game_over_counter == 0:
        # reset game
        # change to state 1
```